# AngularJS: search and display

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a search box where I can search through my JSON file and display the data searched on a table.

Can someone give me some links, if you have one, or teach me how to please?
I can't seem to find it online. All I can find is `ng-repeat`, where the table is already there to begin with, and it's only possible to filter it.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: See http://embed.plnkr.co/Jkp0zdxNFTKQEEMLYAth/preview

Comment: I don't want the data to be already displayed. I only want to display the data when user search for it

Comment: Try adding ng-if to the table to make it display only when searchText is not an empty string. This way the data will not show up until the user searches for something.

Comment: Hmm alright, i'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: post what you are trying

Answer (score 0):

Acctualy i use '| filter' after ng-repeat 
You can find something here in documentation about filter.

[a link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Here we have one exemple as we have on documentation:

```
" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText "
```